# Convert Levenshtein Distance to Error Rate

Tags: machine-learning, computer-science, levenshtein-distance, information-theory

Is their a way to convert levenstein distances to error rates?

With the error rate being the fraction of the sequence that is not **exactly** the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to normalize Levenshtein distance to [0, 1]? That's

```
d(a,b) / max(len(a), len(b))
```

The denominator is an upper bound on Levenshtein distance, so this gives a figure between zero and one. Proof: assume (without loss of generality) that `len(a) > len(b)`, then you can always transform `a` into `b` by substituting `len(b)` characters and deleting `len(a) - len(b)` of them, for a total of `len(a) - len(b) + len(b) = len(a)` operations.